# Calculus Optimization Question

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization

Question:
[image: Question]
Solution
[image: Solution]

I don't understand what is done when $S(x)=(L(x))^2$. How does that help? I thought the only way to have solved this is through finding the first derivative and using the chain rule (which they say is messy).

Thanks.
Dan.

Comment: With $S(x)$ you do NOT have square root to derive.Instead, you have a simple polynomial.

Comment: I see that. So if we state that L(x) > 0 its okay to square the function to get rid of the square root?

Comment: If you know that $L(x)>0$ you're allowed

Comment: Be careful. You cannot always square a value in a problem just because you know that it is positive. In this case, we are looking for the minimum distance. The $x$ that makes $L(x)$ a minimum is the same $x$ that makes $L(x)^2$ a minimum. Note that even though $x$ is the same, $L(x)$ is not necessarily equal to $L(x)^2$.

Comment: Understood L(x) doesn't necessarily equal L(x)^2. Thanks John and Tito. Tito has to be one of the must "fun" names to say.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $Im(L)\subset[0,+\infty)$ and $x^2$ is increasing in $[0,+\infty)$.

In this case, $\arg\min L(x) = \arg\min L^2(x)$

Comment: you want to say that the argmins are equal

Comment: Yes, i edited. Thanks